# react-native slider styling on disabled

Tags: react-native, slider, styling

We have a react-native slider component that we don't want the user to be able to update.  However, when we set the slider to disabled, our slider is greyed out, which we do not want.  How can we disable sliding for the slider while keeping the original styling (not having the slider grayed out)?

edit:
using react-native slider component https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/slider.html

Comment: What slider do you use? Please provide more information about your issue.

Comment: @Raymond using the default slider https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/slider.html

Comment: Does the implementation assigns a new className on disabled to the input element or does it add a disabled attribute to the input element?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I don't see any styling related to `disabled` in the JS implementation... must be handled on the native end.  Still digging...

Comment: What about assigning your own style like https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html and then make the css work it out?

Comment: @Jankapunkt might be worth looking into.  Just need to figure out how to compensate for the greying out--if possible.  will check the source code, not sure if we can set the alpha to 125% tho lol...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<Slider />` is backed by the native `UISlider` and grays out when `disabled` for accessibility reasons. What `<Slider disabled={true} />` does is to set .enabled = NO in the native implementation. What you're looking to do instead is to have it set .userInteractionEnabled = NO. Unfortunately the current implementation of RCTSliderManager (as of React Native 0.44) does not currently support this but it should be super trivial to open a PR with this change.

Comment: Thinking in long term this is the way to go.

Comment: and four years and five months later, this hasn't been done.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue (6 years later) with the '@react-native-community/slider' package. Temporarily resolved (while awaiting an official solution) by placing a transparent view in front of the slider...

It's really not a clean solution, but for now, it works.

```
<View className="justify-center flex-1">
  <Slider
    style={{ width: "100%", height: 40 }}
    value={value}
    minimumValue={minValue}
    maximumValue={maxValue}
    step={step}
    onSlidingComplete={(value) => doYourStuff()}
  />
  {
    disabled && (
      <View
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          width: "100%",
          height: 40,
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
        }}
      />
    )
  }
</View>
```